# how to generate unique id using java and mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to make java class that generate the unique id for lecturerID field when user make his/her id it will always be unqiue so how to do it in java and store that in mysql?
and how should I display the  generated id to the particular user

Comment: Don't. Let the DB do that for you, that's what autoIncrement is for.

Comment: why not creating this  `lecturerID` as  `serial` in your db table and it'll increment automaticly

Comment: @bRIMOsBor what are you talking about? in the code? in the db? anyway, even if it is put in the db as an id-field, unless autoincrement is activated, no, it won't.

Comment: @Stultuske , in mysql you should declare the type as serial to A-I ,otherwise it won't!

Comment: @bRIMOsBor actually: CREATE TABLE table1_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
); is what is needed. don't see any 'SERIAL' in there.

Comment: @Stultuske SERIAL is an alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE.

Comment: In db I have activated auto_increment field for lecturerID but how should I display incremented id for the new user whoever is getting registered?

Comment: @bRIMOsBor and why forcing to use BigInt?

Comment: @Pooja while registering, you don't. You can show it in a message after registration succeeded, something like 'congratulations, your Id = '...

Comment: @Stultuske        `PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Insert into newlect (lectid, lectName, Pswd, lectDept) values(null, ?, ?, ?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);                  
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.setString(1, s1); //  lecturerID must generate          
    ps.setString(3, s8); // password           
   ps.setString(4, s6);  // dept                       
   ps.setString(2, s2); // name
 ResultSet tableKeys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
 tableKeys.next();                       
 tableKeys.getInt(1);
    ps.executeUpdate(); `.  this code is not working :(

Comment: only normal. You are passing a value that is already set by your db.
you shouldn't try to pass a lectId anymore, especially not one with a null value.

Comment: @Stultuske so should I even remove `ps.setString(1, s1);`. ?